# how to get latest x directory folder entries using F#

Tags: .net, search, f#

I was stuck trying to figure out a method of getting the latest n folders in a particular root directory using F#.  The code below is the outcome of that journey and I wanted to post here and share the code sample to help other engineers trying to solve a similar problem.

```
open System  
open System.IO  

// only get the N latest FOLDERS in a directory    
let getLatestNFolders (rootDirectory:string) (howmany:int) =  
    let latestFolders =  
        Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory)   
        |> Seq.cache  
        |> Seq.map(fun filePath -> (filePath,   Directory.GetCreationTime(filePath)))  
        |> Seq.sortBy(fun (path, time) -> -time.Ticks) // descending order  
        |> Seq.take(howmany)
        |> Seq.map(fun (path, time) -> path)  
        |> Set.ofSeq  
    latestFolders  

let results =  getLatestNFolders "c:\\temp" 3

results |> Seq.iter(fun path -> printfn "%s\n" path)
```

Comment: @louie-bacaj -  Thank you.

Comment: A better format for this would be to propose a genuine question and then put the code in an answer

Comment: @Dotcomputercraft I'm afraid SO might close your post as "not a question" if you do not rephrase it as such. You can just post your useful code snippet as an answer - and change the post to be a question. That's a perfectly fine thing to do! As a side-note, there is also http://www.fssnip.net, which is a perfect place for sharing snippets like this one.

Comment: You don't have to map to a tuple, then sort by second, and then map back to first. You can sort by modification time right away.

Comment: A very slight change I would make is swapping the `howmany` and `rootDirectory` arguments. In actual code the directory is probably much more likely to change, so this would improve viability for partial application and pipeability.

Comment: Other than that, as has been mentioned, Stack Overflow isn't the ideal place for this; on the Stack Exchange network, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would have been more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some improvements, mostly focused on removing some cruft:

```
// only get the N latest FOLDERS in a directory    
let getLatestNFolders (rootDirectory:string) howmany =  
    Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory)   
    |> Seq.sortBy(fun path -> -Directory.GetCreationTime(path).Ticks) // descending order  
    |> Seq.take howmany
```

Comment: Thank you John.  I like the improvements.

Comment: Note that if you are using f# 4.0 you can use Seq.sortByDescending.